# Error while connecting my project with the firebase to send push notifications

Tags: swift, firebase, react-native, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to connect my app to firebase to send notification but there i have an error:

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

in the General Capabilities there is no any error.
in code the same there is no any error but when I build and Run there is this error.
While creating certificates also there is wasn't any errors. 
[Here is how the errror is look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L76Ja.png) . Please help!

Here is the piece of code that I wrote:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  COAP
//
//  Created by Azamat Bolegenov on 23.05.17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Azamat Bolegenov. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreData
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseMessaging


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
        let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        print("MessageID:: \(userInfo["gcm_message_id"]!)")
        print(userInfo)
    }




    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Build Settings > Other Linker Flags > on a new line $(inherited).

Do a Cmd+Ctrl+K for a clean, and then build